# How to deduplicate mostly similar values?

Tags: php

I have a database with a column of University names. These values were collected via free-form user text input. So, there are actually a lot of duplicate values, however, they are not exactly the same.

For example:

```
Washington St. University
Washington State University
Washington  State University
WASHINGTON STATE UNIVERSITY
Washington State
WSU
```

[complete list](https://pastebin.com/raw/Ssp9Ct2n)

How should I go about removing duplicates from this list? I've considered using php functions like [`levenshtein`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) and [`similar_text`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) and tuning thresholds for match exclusion. But I'm wondering if there's a better way before I go digging too deep down the rabbit hole.

I'm looking for answers that give a conceptual strategy or algorithms for tackling the problem. I'm happy with any programming language or just pseudo-code.

Comment: Load the data into a spreadsheet of your choosing and put the standardized name next to the input name.  The sooner you start, the sooner you'll be finished.

Comment: What database are you in?  It makes a big difference in functions like this

Comment: for sql-server i think there is a data quality tool that you can use. http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/feature/SQL-Servers-Data-Quality-Services-makes-cleanup-a-cinch

Comment: @Twelfth it's in Microsoft SQL Server (tagged tsql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 ways...your style and your data will be the key in deciding which route.

1 - Translation table.  Create a table with 2 columns, first column is input.  Populate value with a distinct list of all those misc terms.  Manually go through (in a spreadsheet is easier) each one of these inputs and populate the 'display' name.  Gordon's comment is to this extent...I've used a temp company to hire 15 people for a week to categorize search terms like this once, it can be quite the exercise if your distinct input list is huge.

2 - Levenshtein Distance.  This isn't the prettiest but works for the majority (80/20 rule)  https://blog.pythian.com/implementing-fuzzy-search-in-sql-server-part-2-levenshtein-distance/   There's a good chunk of configuration here and it's not very simple (IE, which of the 6 variations of washington state should it be grouping them all as?).  In my past experience, I cross joined the table to itself...used Levenshtein distance between table1.input and table2.input and a count to find out which term had the most matches to it.  It's a huge rabbit hole, be prepped if this is the route you are going....good learning experience at any rate.

3. 3rd party tool.  If you are in a Business Intelligence setting, some of the BI tools out there now have some ability to tackle this.  There is also a data quality tool from microsoft, and a few other options.  Honestly, these guys have just done option 2 for you and you'll pay a third party for that work.

You can somewhat combine option 1 and 2 as well...Create the table with inputs as per the first step, use a script to populate the 'display' column that uses levenshtien, then manually go through the data and correct as needed.